# Make an Xbox 360 controller with an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I was thinking of making a custom Xbox 360 controller (racing wheel) with the Arduino Uno plugged into the Xbox. How would I emulate the buttons/triggers on the original controller with the Arduino? Is there a library that can help me do this?

Comment: you may or may not be able to do it with your Uno .... it depends on the kind of the USB to serial converter the board uses ..... what kind of a chip do you see near the USB connector?

Comment: I googled a bit at this topic. It seems, that at least most (if not all) Xbox360 controller emulations/DIY builds cannot be used with the Xbox360 itself, but only with a PC. The reason is, that a Xbox controller incorporates an extra security chip, which performs some form of handshake, before the console really accepts the controller. Some sites stated, that some chinese producers cracked that chip, to produce knockoffs, but I couldn't find a hint to a published crack. It might exist,  you may have to google much. If you find something, this will most likely be no beginner project.

Comment: If you decide, that using it only with a PC is ok, you should look at Arduino boards, that have a configurable USB connection, so that the Arduino can behave as a HID device. This is also possible with the Uno, but not as good and only with reflashing the USB to serial controller.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Would I be able to emulate it with something more powerful like a raspberry pi? I also searched some more and found some stuff about PID and VID, is this what you meant by the security key or is there more to it? P.S here is a tutorial I was referring: [link](https://hackaday.com/2015/07/14/using-a-teensylc-to-emulate-the-xbox-360-controller/). There was also this repo on the ["falcon panel"](https://github.com/candera/falconpanel)

Comment: PID and VID are definitions for the USB connection. They are used to identifiy the type of a device, that is connected via USB. Seems, that it can be changed. But despite that it will still just advertise itself as HID device. If you google for Xbox360 controller emulation, you find many people, who talk about a real extra chip on the controllers pcb, which does some kind of secret handshake. Without a real crack for this, you won't be able to get any DIY controller working with the Xbox360. Microsoft uses the security chip to actively prevent others from doing this.

Comment: VID and PID are just numbers that are associated with a Vendor and Product. They don't define *what* it is, only who it is and what it's called.  What it *does* is defined by the device descriptor - a large block of data that defines protocols, endpoint types, block sizes, etc.

Comment: The [GIMX](https://gimx.fr) open source project may help. The GIMX adapter plugs into the console and a computer running Windows or Linux (raspberry pi has experiemental support). A real xbox controller must be plugged into the computer so it can do the xbox authentication. Off the shelf or custom controllers plugged into the same computer can talk to the Xbox console.

Comment: Ohh... That looks interesting. This might work! Thanks for the suggestion. Will let you know if this works out.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Uno's do not have a native USB Connection. However, if you use an Arduino Leonardo or Pro Micro, you can use MHeironimus's Joystick library, However I am not sure if they are specifically compatible with the XBox.

https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary